# Install a debug compiled pgm on a "new" computer

Tags: c#, .net, visual-c++, dll, filesystems

I have a huge project that includes C# & C++ and many .dll's.
on my computer everything runs just fine.
BUT - when i copy the whole "debug" folder (with all of the user needed dll's and configuration files) to a new formatted computer - **i fail to run**.

i installed on the new computer:
.NET 4.7 framework
visual c++ redistribution's (2015, 2017.. x86 x64.. everything i think)
but it didn't help

after i installed `Visual Studio Build-Tools` though, **it worked just fine**.
the problem is that it's a very big installation (4GB+/-) and i don't want to install that on my costumers computers (now we are on testing phase, no `release` compilations yet.)

i wrote a small program that runs `dumpbin` on all of the project's dll's, takes their dependencies and searches for them in the file system.
i found out that i miss some (debugging?) dll's in my system, such as:
MSVCP140D.DLL

VCRUNTIME140D.DLL

UCRTBASED.DLL

**what if so should i do in order to be able to run this pgm on a 'naked' computer, or how do i manage to install these missing dlls?**

Comment: Have you tried to build for release, and copy the content of the `release` folder rather than `debug`?

Comment: yep. but after building for `release` it's not even running on my computer b/c some components are not ready for that yet.    
therefore it must be done in `DEBUG`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. You can't run a debug application on your target computer without the build tools being installed. The problem is that the debug versions of the C++ redistribution DLLs are not part of the normal redistribute package.

You find the list of DLLs that are part of the C++ redistribution package [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kche8ah.aspx). Your only option is to manually copy these three DLLs over to the target computer if you don't want to install the build tools.

If you build your application with the release target, the release versions of the DLLs will be used. They got the same name, without the `D` suffix. These DLLs are part of the [*Visual C++ Redistributable for Visual Studio 2015*](https://www.microsoft.com/en-US/download/details.aspx?id=48145).

So your options are:

1. Copy the DLLs to your new system
2. Install the build tools on your new system
3. Use the release target when building your application

Comment: thank for the answer, although it's very disappointing... i already tried coping these 3 dll's to `c:\windows\system32` but it didn't help.  now i'll try to copy into `c:\Windows\SysWOW64` as well and hope for different results.... **are the dll's different for each folder? or can i copy the same file for both?**

Comment: Did you try just placing them in the directory where your application is? Usually that works.

Comment: Did you copy the debug versions of all DLLs in the redistributable package? Each of the DLLs may have some additional dependencies on their own.

Comment: i'm not sure i understand u correctly, but i installed all redistributables packs. now i format my computer again... but i would appreciate if u will give me some more details of what and how should i do....